# Powershell: UTF-8 value of special character

Tags: powershell, utf-8

I need to replace char:

```
Ť
```

with something like this:

```
\u0164
```

I have following simple try

```
function ReplaceNonISOChar($val) {
    $regex = [regex] $('[^\u0000-\u00ff]')
    $res = ""
    foreach ($char in [char[]]$val) {
        $utf = '{0:d4}' -f [int][char]$char + "" 
        $res += $char -replace $regex, "\u$utf"
    }
    return $res
}
$result = ReplaceNonISOChar -val 'Ť'
Write-Host $result
```

But it returns me integer value (not unicode). If regex can hit the pattern and find this char, it should be possible within powershell retrieve also this value backwards.

Can anybody give me some hints?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. What you are trying to do? Though you could just replace one char with another `$val -replace [char]356,[char]164
`

Comment: i need the unicode value of "Ť" char. because 3rd party has only ISO-8896-1 encoding so i need to replace all UTF-8 chars that are not in ISO-8896-1. so i need \u0164

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to UTF-8. Did you mean UTF-16? (Both are character encodings for the Unicode character set but \u is a notation for UTF-16 code units.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of decimal (`d`) you should tell the script to use hexadecimal (`x`) notation:

```
$utf = '{0:x4}' -f [int][char]$char + ""
```

Comment: u saved me. Thanks a lot!!